# Insert into table the selected columns from another table

Tags: sql, insert

What query would insert the selected columns, for a desired value, from a table into another table?

Before Query

```
table1=>Colums(A,B,C)
  row1(a,b,1)
  row2(c,d,0)
  row3(e,f,1)

table2=>Columns(id,A,B)
```

After Query

```
table1 is unchanged.

table2(id,A,B)
  row1(id,a,b)
  row2(id,e,f)
```

I need to insert in table2 all the rows from table1 where 'C=1', C may equal 1 in multiple records.

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? ...?

Answer (score 11):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(A,B,C)
SELECT A,B,C
FROM TABLE1
WHERE C = 1
```

Comment: Without `INTO` it will only work on SQL Server and MySQL, if you add `INTO` it will work pretty much on any database.

Answer (score 0):

you can also select all the columns into a table without creating it first:

```
SELECT *
INTO TABLE2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE C=1
```